# POST http://localhost:8080/storeSqlData.php 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, mysqli, ejs

I want to send data from .ejs file (i.e javascript ..because .ejs file embedds  tag)  to mysql database and i figured out the way to do that was through PHP file as a mediator. But here i am getting error -

```
POST http://localhost:8080/storeSqlData.php 404 (Not Found)
```

as soon as i load my localhost:8080 on browser - chrome.

I have put my .php file out my project folder, inside project folder and inside every folders of the project folder, but to no avail. Please help me find a solution as none from internet helped.

**app.ejs** -

```
<html>

<head>

  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBwgU_zhAo8cKy6THHRrcpwtaM&callback=initMap">
  </script>
</head>

<body>


  <div id="floating-panel">
    <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Sydney, NSW">

    <div>
      <button id="submit" type="submit" value="Insert and View Location">Insert and View Location</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="map"></div>

  <script>


    // NEW CODE 
    function initMap() {

      loadXMLDoc();
    }


    function loadXMLDoc() {
      console.log("Inside loadXMLDoc()");
      var address = document.getElementById('address').value;

      var xmlhttp;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("address").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }

      data = "name=" + address;
      console.log("PHP Data = ", data);
      xmlhttp.open("POST", "storeSqlData.php", true);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xmlhttp.send(data);
    }

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**storeSqlData.php - **

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST)){
   $value = $_POST['name'];
  // $website = $_POST['website'];


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "locationsData";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO locations (value) VALUES ($value)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

 }
 ?>
```

Comment: are you using a server or you just throw it in a plain folder? You need an active server running to actually execute your script

Comment: no ..  just plain folder

Comment: What server d you suggest ?

Comment: It is not something I suggest,.. You "need" an Apache server. There are other way but mostly install apache, point it to a folder and throw the php in there